# get records between from a start to end number

Tags: php, mysql, json, record, between

This SQL return all records as (JSON) from 2 tables "`posts_main`" and "`posts_comments`" that depends on specific User

```
$sql = "select posts_main.*,
(select groupid from posts_comments where groupid = posts_main.id group by groupid ) as count_comments
from posts_main
WHERE posts_main.user_id = '$user_id' ";


$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $obj->table, $obj->limit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
```

**My Question:**
how can I get the first 10 records, then the next 10 records, to the end?

**For example:** 
I'll send "start" = 0, I'll get the first 10 records.
Next time I'll send: "start" = 10, then I'll get the records **FROM** 10 **TO** 20.
and so on.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "start" number, you can frame your query like this -

```
$sql = "select posts_main.*,
(select groupid from posts_comments where groupid = posts_main.id group by groupid ) as count_comments
from posts_main
WHERE posts_main.user_id = '$user_id' limit 10,10";
```

MySQL reads 10 records starting at the 11th record in the table. 
If you are looking for a Prev, Next solution then PHP pagination is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
$start = 0;
$sql = "select posts_main.*,
(select groupid from posts_comments where groupid = posts_main.id group by groupid ) as count_comments
from posts_main
WHERE posts_main.user_id = '$user_id' 
limit '$start' 10";
```